# How to create a class that "partially inherits" another class or just implements some members and functions from another class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

As title said, I have a class just call it `User` that has to implement some of the properties of another fixed class `UserData` but not all of them. However, it is not work if I directly make `User` inherits `UserData` because there are some virtual functions in `UserData` which are not necessary in `User`. So how should I do?

In addition, I would not make `UserData` inherits `User` because of some restrictions of business logic, and, **`UserData` should not be modified or implement any interface.**

**UserData**

```cs
public class UserData
{
    private string _aS;
    public string AS
    {
        get { return _aS; }
        set { _aS = value; }
    }

    private string _bS;
    public virtual string BS
    {
        get { return _bS; }
        set { _bS = value; }
    }

    private string _cS;
    public virtual string CS
    {
        get { return _cS; }
        set { _cS = value; }
    }
}
```

**User**

```
public class User
{
    private string _aS;     // Same as Daddy's
    public string AS
    {
        get { return _aS; }
        set { _aS = value; }
    }

    private string _bS;    // Same as Daddy's
    public virtual string BS
    {
        get { return _bS; }
        set { _bS = value; }
    }

    /* _cS should not be included in Baby */
}
```

Comment: use interfaces. theres no partial inheritance or multiple inheritance in c#

Comment: Can you post a more concrete example than "baby" and "daddy"? We will be able to give you a better answer if we understand your problem domain better.

Comment: If you own the classes then change them so it fits your needs. Meaning put the `AS`and `BS` in a class. Inherit this class in `Daddy` and add `CS` to daddy. Inherit it in `Baby` too. To be honest, the way you have it, `Daddy` should inherit `Baby`

Comment: @Dai Let me clarify more specifically. Daddy is a class that should be fixed with the properties I mentioned so it should implement any interface, or it should not be altered.

Comment: `User` should **encapsulate** `UserData`. It should have a private `UserData` variable which it can access as needed. Then add whatever properties / methods to `User` that make sense. Those properties / methods can access the private `UserData` if necessary.

Comment: You say: `In addition, I would not make UserData inherits User because of some restrictions of business logic, and, UserData should not be modified or implement any interface.` If that's the case, there is no way to achieve what you are after. Simple.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, It is not a sealed class, derive a class with the interface, cast, and voila: Common accessible properties in a single type.

Comment: @strom `UserData should not be modified or implement any interface.`

Comment: @strom`or implement any interface.`

Comment: @CodingYoshi, That only applies to `UserData` since it most likely external and cannot be modified. However, since it is not sealed there is no reason it cannot be derived from and the new class that implements the interface through the existing base properties. Use the derived class in the program. Any new or modified instances of the new class can always be cast back to `UserData` for consumption in the underlying "business layer".

Comment: @strom I am not sure where you're going with this. The OP said they cannot, I repeat, they **cannot** implement an interface and you're saying to implement an interface and you also said this in your answer. Then you start talking about casting and business layers etc. What am I missing here? It should be crystal clear this is not an option according to OP: `UserData: Interface`. I am not saying this. The OP is.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, You missed the last of the OPs comments to my answer, which indicated two applications: `It's the business model from the main application that should not be modified in my application `.  This statement implies the OPs program is free to do anything it wishes.  `UserData should not be modified or implement any interface` Both clauses directly relate to `UserData`.  It states nothing of deriving a class from `UserData`. This will be my last word on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195841/discussion-between-strom-and-codingyoshi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# uses interfaces to establish common properties and methods.

Use Interfaces that define the common elements of both classes.

```cs
public Interface UserInfo
{

    string AS {get; set;}

    string BS {get; set;}
}
```

You can still use a base class, it must be the first one in the list i.e. after the ":".

```
public class UserData: UserInfo
```

```
public class User: UserInfo
```

Since BOTH classes **already** implement the Interface there is no changes other than deriving them from the interface.

### Edit

Since the `UserData` class cannot be modified (for whatever reason, externally defined or publicly exposed through and `API`) and is not `sealed`, it is possible to derive a class from it and add the interface:

```
public class UserData1: UserData, UserInfo
{
// since the base class already implements the public properties as defined 
// in the interface, no implementation is required here

// however any defined constructors in the base class must be present here:
    // repeat per constructor
    public UserData1() : base() // add parameters: UserData1(int i):base(i)
    {
      // this can be left empty
    }
}
```

A completely fictional use case:

Assumes:

`BusinessLogic.UserData` is passed in to the method as:

`List<BusinessLogic.UserData> userData`. and a single BusinessLogic.UserData value for completeness.

A class level array, already instantiated and populated, is available as `public User[] users`.

This also requires `using System.Linq;" for the bulk type conversion.

```
public void ProcessAll(List<BusinessLogic.UserData> userData,BusinessLogic.UserData single)
{
   List<UserInfo> AllData = new List<UserInfo>();

   AllData.AddRange(userData.ConvertAll(new Converter<BusinessLogic.UserData, UserInfo>(i => i as UserData1))); 
   AllData.AddRange(users);
   // cast the single and add it to the list
   AllData.Add((UserInfo)((UserData1)single));// note the extra cast
   foreach(var user in AllData)
   {      
 //note CS is not available from AllData since it is not defined in the interface
      // not the most elegant code, but proves the point
      Console.WriteLine("AS=" + user.AS + " BS=" + user.BS);
   }
   //Let us replace the first element in userData with itself from AllData does nothing, but shows how to do this.
   if(AllData[0] is BusinessLogic.UserData)
//since add order is maintained in a list this if is not needed.
      userData[0] = (BusinessLogic.UserData)AllData[0];

   // since BusinessLogic.UserData is a reference type(class not struct) we can modify CS, but only if it is cast back to BusinessLogic.UserData first
   if(AllData[0] is BusinessLogic.UserData)
         ((BusinessLogic.UserData)AllData[0]).CS="Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Let me clarify more specifically. Daddy is a class that should be fixed with the properties I mentioned so it should implement any interface, or it should not be altered

Comment: Yes, just see Daddy as a fixed class.

Comment: @TomFong, Fixed or `sealed`?

Comment: not `sealed`. Just cannot change the content of Daddy (UserData)

Comment: @mjwills It's the business model from the main application that should not be modified in my application